# Is there any software (open source and/or free) that reads chess notation?

Tags: software, notation

I would like to convert a chess notation into a game. How to do that?

I have a game in algebraic notation, let say,

```
1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 h6 3.d4 e6 4.c3 Nf6 5.Bd3 a6 6.Bc2 Be7 7.Qd3 b5 8.b3 Qc7
9.Nbd2 Bb7 10.0-0  c4 11.bxc4 bxc4 12.Qe2 0-0 13.Nxc4 d5 14.Nce5 dxe4 
15.Nh4 Qxc3 16.Be3 Nc6 17.Nxc6 Bxc6 18.Rac1 Bb5 19.Qd1 Bxf1 20.Qxf1 Qa5 
21.Bb3 Rfc8 22.Rd1 Qh5 23.g3 Ng4 24.Ng2
```

Is there any software that reads this?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific. What do you expect the output to be, exactly? If you just want a viewable, interactive board with those moves populated into it, there are tons of free PGN viewers available online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are several.

Your question is very vague, though. [Arena](http://www.playwitharena.com/) is an OK choice if you're on Windows; otherwise [Lichess](http://lichess.org) is an online option. All of these are free, but there are many more, both free and costly ones (but I don't have enough reputation for more links, and I don't know exactly what you're after).

The computer-readable format of algebraic notation is called Portable Game Notation (PGN), which might help you with searching for alternatives.